# PowerShell: "Eject Device" like Windows' "Safely Remove", possible?

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, disk

I want to get the same effect as clicking an "Eject Device" on the "Safely Remove" menu in the Notification Area. Is this possible with PowerShell? I have tried `Get-PhysicalDisk`, and I could see that PowerShell can get the details of the disk I want to remove. So, I want to do emulate "Eject Device" with the uniquely-identifiable information of that disk (like "Number" or "Serial Number").

If this is NOT possible with PowerShell, please tell me that.

If Microsoft has not exposed any programmatic access to that feature, so this is NOT possible in a reasonable way (other than a really difficult way like reverse-engineering or something), please tell me that, too.

[image]

Comment: dont know about powershell, but in api need call [`CM_Request_Device_Eject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_request_device_ejectw)

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. At least it is possible. If there is no PowerShell way, I will just create a C++ console application using that API.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/130887/dismount-usb-external-drive-using-powershell

Comment: @SimonMourier I saw that before posting this, but that is not applicable in my case. The drives have no recognisable partition, so I cannot eject it using a Windows drive letter. I have to use the disk information like the "Number" or "Serial Number". Also, the disk can be SATA-hotswap, not just USB.

Comment: if you want remove disk, you need first `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` than call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW` with `DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId`, `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` and finally `CM_Request_Device_Eject `

Comment: You should mention what you have tried/seen/tested in your question.